# Separating strings by a char after join method

Tags: javascript, string, char, arguments, parameter-passing

So I am just messing around with functions and creating my own to make sure I understand concepts better. I wrote out this one below and it seems to be almost there, however I have one issue.

```
function strAdd() {
    let strResult = '';
    let numResult = 0;
    for (let i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] ===  'string') {
            let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[i])
            strResult += args.join("");
        } else if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
            numResult += arguments[i];
        }
      
    }
  return console.log(`this string says ${strResult} and the numbers add up to ${numResult}`);
}
```

When ever I print out the the strings, they are still being logged out as one string as opposed to separate strings so

```
strAdd('here', 10, 'are', 10, 2, 'the', 35, 'strings')
```

Gives me

```
this string says herearethestrings and the numbers add up to 57
```

Whenever I try adding different chars into the join method, all it does is separates the chars within each string by the specified char and not the string itself.
So

```
strResult += args.join(" ");
```

would give me

```
this string says h e r ea r et h es t r i n g s and the numbers add up to 57
```

instead of splitting up the chars. I notice how the strings are still being joined too. Any thoughts on how I can refactor this code?

Comment: You wish for output such as `here are the strings`? (for the strings part)

Comment: You have it right in the `numResult` section, why didn't you just use that same logic with the strings?

Comment: @pilchard I originally went with that logic but it gave me the strings as one joint string as I mentioned above. When I did some research that was a solution that I found, it worked, but only for separating the chars within each string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish for output such as "here are the strings" (and even if not) you should understand the different parameters. Arrays and Strings have a lot in common but they are different types. When you `split` or convert to array (`slice`) or `join` you might change from one type to another. But no worries. you can always `join("")` or `split("")` to swap from one to another.

```js
function strAdd() {
  var arr_string_arguments = []
  let numResult = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arguments[i] === 'string') {
      var str = arguments[i]
      arr_string_arguments.push(str)
    } else if (typeof arguments[i] === 'number') {
      numResult += arguments[i];
    }
  }
  var strResult = arr_string_arguments.join(" ");
  
  return console.log(`this string says "${strResult}" and the numbers add up to ${numResult}`);
}

strAdd('here', 10, 'are', 10, 2, 'the', 35, 'strings')
```

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. If I may ask, since you mentioned how different arrays & strings operate...would there be a way to do this holding that data with a string? I did research and the first thing I found was using an array, but I am curious if I could get away without doing so?

Comment: You could have `str = str + " "` instead (as you did with numbers) that is the simple approach. But it has 2 flows. It will leave you with extra " ". Also performance will degrade.

Comment: Okay thank you for the explanation!

Crazy enough i'm in a bootcamp and that exact logic came up in one of my challenge codes a few weeks ago. At that time I thought a lot of those methods like join() only lived on the Array class. Whole new world for me